# How do you get all cells in an excel worksheet to be in one column using VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

How do you get all cells in an excel worksheet to be in one column using VBA code?

Any simple VBA ideas that could work?

I tried using a vba code already that isn't working for some reason. Note code with *** *** as trouble area. The code below works sometimes, but not always. No clue.

```
Dim arr As Variant, lLoop1 As Long, lLoop2 As Long
Dim arr2 As Variant, lIndex As Long

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With


ReDim arr2(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Count - ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count)

arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value


For lLoop1 = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    For lLoop2 = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        ***If Len(Trim(arr(lLoop1, lLoop2))) > 0 Then***
            arr2(lIndex) = arr(lLoop1, lLoop2)
            lIndex = lIndex + 1
        End If
    Next
Next

Sheets.Add
Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Value = arr2

Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Copy
Range("A2").Resize(lIndex + 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
Rows(1).Delete

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True

    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Qualitative Variable"
End With
```

Comment: VBA can do pretty much anything, but can you please clarify what you mean?  _"get all cells in an excel worksheet to be in one column"_ is extremely broad and unclear...  Any sample data you could give would be helpful also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This short macro will take all the non-blank cells from *Sheet1* and place them in a single column in *Sheet2:*

```
Sub Columnize()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim K As Long
    K = 1
    For Each r In s1.UsedRange
        If r.Value <> "" Then
        r.Copy s2.Cells(K, 1)
        K = K + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Adjust the code for your sheet names and destination address.

Comment: This code works for some cases. But sometimes I get a "Run time error 13" with "type mismatch" error. It wants me to debug when I get to "If r.Value <> "" Then"   .....    

Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: This may occur if you are trying to pickup cells that contain **error values** .............try replacing **.Value** with **.Text**

Comment: Perfect when I replace the .Value with .Text. Takes some time for larger files, but it gets the job done exactly as needed. Thanks a bunch!